# Apache2 sites-available config

Tags: linux, apache, debian

First off, I have done the searching and found answers but I still don't understand the below.

I have two .co.uk domains, with two directories setup on my Debian box in /home/site1/public_html/ & /home/site2/public_html/ - (examples, users have been setup etc).

So I point my domains to my boxes IP address, with two DNS entries (same for both):

```
DNS Entry      Type      IP Address
@              A         myip
www            A         myip
```

Now for the sites-available config I create two new "files", both are setup the same, but the paths and info are changed for the respective domains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my-email-address
    ServerName www.site1.co.uk
    ServerAlias site1.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/site1/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

&

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my-email-address
    ServerName www.site2.co.uk
    ServerAlias site2.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/site2/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

I a2ensite, reload apache.

Now if I go to www.site1.co.uk OR site1.co.uk it works fine.
If I got to www.site2.co.uk it works, but site2.co.uk doesn't work (page not found), and I literally have no idea why.

Can someone explain this to me? Whether I should be adding some other DNS entry, different configuration etc?

Regards,

Comment: `ping site2.co.uk` has the same ip address as `ping www.site2.co.uk`?

Comment: Host not found without the "www." It's weird, it works for one site but not the other :s

Comment: check DNS, record for the domain doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, you need to redirect site2.co.uk to www.site2.co.uk.

Here's how you should do in Apache2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.site2\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.site2.co.uk/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

For further information refer https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html - Canonical Hostnames.

Comment: to use mod_rewrite must be a request to the server, in this case the domain doesn't match the IP address.